# Anatomically Correct Dullahan's Horse

Tags: anatomy, mythical-creatures, anatomically-correct

The Dullahan is a spirit that rides on a rather unique type of horse

This horse, like the rider, does not have its head attached to its body. Instead, the head floats behind the body. Furthermore, the head is in fact larger than the body itself. Another unique trait of these animals is the fire which they produce out of their hooves and nostrils

If this horse was a living creature made of flesh, how could it be made to fit together inside? Include how would it eat and drink, and how the head works at all

Comment: Is this [Dullahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dullahan) you're talking about? I'm not editing your question again, I've recalled you enough times it's preferable to give your references when talking about less-known mythological creatures.

Comment: I don't see any references to the black horse being headless. Can you provide textual support for this question? Either that or remove the ACS tag. Otherwise, VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Two in One

This horse will have to be split into two different animals, the body and the head

## Body

The body will be the most normal of the 2 animals. Most of the anatomy can be left the same as a horse. The main changes will be in the neck, hooves, and nervous system

### Neck

The neck will have to be the place of the mouth and breathing hole. The best solution, both functional and aesthetically fitting, would be a toothy maw, like a hagfish, formed from a pair of cervical ribs and moved by the standard neck muscles of a horse. Breathing would be achieved by a serpentine glottis in this mouth. They could feed on effectively any foodstuff with this arrangement. On drinking, they would simply need to go further in to submerge their throat and let water in

### Hooves

The hooves will need special adaptations to produce fire. One way to allow this would be some sort of volatile pyrophoric mixture secreted in organs found above the legs. The legs themselves would have vessels that connect to the frog of the hoof, which can open up to let out a stream of flame from their hooves

### Nervous System

This is the easiest to solve: Simply insert a brain somewhere in the body. The ideal place should be somewhere under the spine, in the chest, as this is well protected and close to the main nerve cords. The senses also must be considered. A pair of eyes or ears above the spine, at the end of the neck, should serve them well to navigate, and tastebuds and olfactory bulbs in the throat would be useful to find food

## Head

The head has some more serious issues for the horse

### Floating

The only way for these skulls to float is some manner of lifting gas. Hydrogen is the most efficient, and can easily be made biologically. Most of the head will be a hydrogenous air-space, to allow the thing to float

### Locomotion

The only reasonable solution to moving this thing would be to add wings. However, if it is a domesticated animal, it wouldn't necessarily need to move by itself: Instead, it simply could be dragged along using a bridle. At this point, any moves it must do by itself could be handled by a set of air jets, ideally set into the back of the jaw between the angles of the mandible

### Innards

The internal organs need to be placed somewhere. A good spot would be the region occupied by the lower jaw: It is low down and stable, and is close to the large mouth orifice. Food and air will enter through a set of openings near the chin, with feces exiting via a pore in the underside of the head

The brain, however, will likely have to be nearer the eyes. A solution could be a pair of ganglia behind the eyes, connecting to a brain in the middle near the nasal cavity

### Fire

The fire can be handled just as with the hooves, just with bigger flame organs to match the bigger nostrils. This could also help ballast the head so it sits at a more horse-like slant